# zsh code that counts actual number of printed characters on prompt

Tags: script, zsh

would greatly appreciate it if anyone could shed some light about anything concerning this cryptic line of code:

```
${${(%):-$1%$y(l.1.0)}[-1]}
```

I got this line of code from this page:
https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/cgbm24/multiline_prompt_the_missing_ingredient/

Comment: It's a subscope of [your previous question](https://superuser.com/q/1735824/432690), right?

Comment: yes that is correct